# UIBarButtonItem backButton setting image with no back text causes title alignment issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I am wanting to use an image for my `backButton` in my `navigationController`. I just want the image used, with no "back" text shown at all, so I did:

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ZSSBackButton.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 25, 0, 0)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, backButtonImage.size.height*2) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This works well, but seems to have the side effect to making long `navigationItem` titles appear to be off center, even though it really is just leaving white space where the backbutton text should be:

[image]

Is there a way that I can bring the title a little more to the left?

Comment: Did you get any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage position of UINavigationbar title using **titleView** property.

```
UIView *backView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40)];// Here you can set View width and height as per your requirement for displaying titleLbl position in navigationbar 
[backView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
UILabel *titleLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40)];
[backView addSubview:titleLbl];
titleLbl.text  = @"YOUR TITLE";
titleLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.navigationItem.titleView = backView;
```

EDIT : you can create custom button and assign it to leftbutton as :

```
UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,51,31);
[btnBack setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ZSSBackButton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackProfile_TouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *leftBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBtn];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Yeah, I have done this before, but it is a pain when you have to display a `UIBarButtonItem` on the right. Things get screwed up.

Comment: I have used both many times. Works for me. You need to set backview frame and titlelbl frame as per your need.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I have passed custom button and set left button of navigationbar.

Comment: Yeah but if you use a custom button then you have to control popping the `viewController` back, which I don't want to have to worry about.

Comment: I think if you need to set a large title then this is the only way you can manage this. otherwise you can not show complete title there.

Comment: There isn't a more simple solution like always settings the `backBarItem` to have a nil title?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30780/discussion-between-nishant-tyagi-and-nic-hubbard)